# How do I fill in the rest of the elements in an SQL TRIGGER?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently really stuck with a trigger I'm trying to make. I'm not sure if its because it cant be done or whether I'm just doing it wrong. 
But technically, I need to enter details pretty much default values into a table after getting the ID from the table that was just inserted.

Ex:

In Table Device, I have an ID, Description, Status

In Table Hearing Device, I have an ID, a Model and a Make

What I want to do is, when a new value is entered into the database for the Hearing Device Table, I want to be able to copy the ID of that table into the device table as well as fill in the catalog name, description and AvailabilityStatus

Whenever I try doing this with an INSERT and a Trigger like this

```
INSERT INTO hearing_device
VALUES ('00001','invision','Unique')
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER replicate AFTER INSERT ON b
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO a(deviceCatalogID,deviceCatalogName, deviceDescription, availabilityStatus)
   VALUES (NEW.deviceCatalogID, 'Hearing devices', 'Brand:invision' , 1);
END;
```

I get a Error saying **"truncated incorrect DOUBLE Value: Unique"**

#### Table Definitions

```
CREATE TABLE device (
  deviceCatalogID varchar(5),
  deviceCatalogName varchar(20),
  deviceDescription varchar(300),
  availabilityStatus varchar(100),

  CONSTRAINT pk_device_catalogID PRIMARY KEY (deviceCatalogID)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE hearing_Device (
  deviceCatalogID varchar(5),
  hdMake varchar(20),
  hdModel varchar(20),

  CONSTRAINT pk_hearingDevice_catalogID PRIMARY KEY (deviceCatalogID)
);
```

Comment: Please add your table definitions in full

Comment: Check in about 5 minutes

Comment: The trigger code and the `INSERT` statement (in which you should list the target columns) don't match the table DDL. You should [edit] the question and fix that.

Comment: @stickybit done.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error with the code given - are there any other triggers on hearing device?

Comment: P Salmon No sir. I genuinely have no clue why that error comes up